# Why a string variable can use forEach method by call in JS?

Tags: javascript

```js
var rst = 0;   
var num = 0;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(num + '', function(v){ rst += +v; });
```

You can see from above. `num` is a number, then we convert it to string by `num+''`. The console shows no error.

What make me confused is that `num` is a string, why it can use the `forEach` method?

Answer (score 2):

In all standard compliant JS implementations, any array-like object can use functions from `Array.prototype`, including strings:

```js
var arrayLike = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', length: 3 }; // same as 'abc'

Array.prototype.forEach.call(arrayLike, function(val) {
  console.log(val);  
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It is not detailed as it could be but definitely not wrong.

Comment: Blame @zerkms.  "Any array-like object" is technically incorrect.

Comment: @Tibrogargan how so? The standard uses the term.

Comment: @zerkms since we're being nit-picky It says "to other kinds of objects", not "to other kinds of array-like objects"

Comment: "In most JS implementations" -> "In standard compliant implementations"?

Comment: @Tibrogargan the standard defines all the requirements, for something to be eligible for use with `Array.prototype.forEach` it must be an array-like. By definition.

Comment: @zerkms That particular requirement does not actually seem to be present.  The only requirements seem to be that the thisArg is an Object and that it has a length property.  Give integers a length and test it.

Comment: @Tibrogargan that's right. And it means "array-like"

Comment: @zerkms Make up your mind, quoting you: "Even ES5.1 only requires the .length property and an indexer."

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the `forEach` function that might be a member of the String prototype.  You're explicitly calling the `Array` prototype `forEach` and telling it to treat the `thisArg` as an `Array`.  Depending on your runtime environment the implementation of `forEach` may be browser/environment dependent but at worst it's going to do nothing and silently return `undefined`.

Here's some source from webkit.  There is some array specific code, but in general there's no reason it wouldn't work on pretty much anything.

```
EncodedJSValue JSC_HOST_CALL arrayProtoFuncForEach(ExecState* exec)
{
    JSObject* thisObj = exec->hostThisValue().toObject(exec);
    unsigned length = thisObj->get(exec, exec->propertyNames().length).toUInt32(exec);
    if (exec->hadException())
        return JSValue::encode(jsUndefined());

    JSValue function = exec->argument(0);
    CallData callData;
    CallType callType = getCallData(function, callData);
    if (callType == CallTypeNone)
        return throwVMTypeError(exec);

    JSValue applyThis = exec->argument(1);

    unsigned k = 0;
    if (callType == CallTypeJS && isJSArray(thisObj)) {
        JSFunction* f = jsCast<JSFunction*>(function);
        JSArray* array = asArray(thisObj);
        CachedCall cachedCall(exec, f, 3);
        for (; k < length && !exec->hadException(); ++k) {
            if (UNLIKELY(!array->canGetIndexQuickly(k)))
                break;

            cachedCall.setThis(applyThis);
            cachedCall.setArgument(0, array->getIndexQuickly(k));
            cachedCall.setArgument(1, jsNumber(k));
            cachedCall.setArgument(2, thisObj);

            cachedCall.call();
        }
    }
    for (; k < length && !exec->hadException(); ++k) {
        PropertySlot slot(thisObj);
        if (!thisObj->getPropertySlot(exec, k, slot))
            continue;

        MarkedArgumentBuffer eachArguments;
        eachArguments.append(slot.getValue(exec, k));
        eachArguments.append(jsNumber(k));
        eachArguments.append(thisObj);

        if (exec->hadException())
            return JSValue::encode(jsUndefined());

        call(exec, function, callType, callData, applyThis, eachArguments);
    }
    return JSValue::encode(jsUndefined());
}
```

Comment: "The implementation of that will be browser/environment dependent" --- in what part? The behaviour of `Array.prototype.forEach` is pretty much standardised.

Comment: *"it's probably just going to silently return undefined"* - No, because `.forEach()` is designed to work with array-like objects (including strings) when invoked via `.call()` or `.apply()`. The code shown will work fine.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, the API and behavior of `Array.prototype.forEach` is standard, but the actual implementation is not.

Comment: @Tibrogargan and how is it relevant to the question? The standard **GUARANTEES** the OP's code to work fine. If the implementation is standard compliant - it does not matter how exactly it is implemented.

Comment: "but at worst it's going to do nothing" --- there is no any "worst" case here, the behaviour is standardised.

Comment: @zerkms From the 5.1 standard (15.4.4.18):  "NOTE The forEach function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the forEach function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent"  The behavior is most certainly not standardized.

Comment: @Tibrogargan how about you check modern standards? Even ES5.1 only requires the `.length` property and an indexer. That explicitly allows a string as a valid `this` context for which the behaviour is **strictly known**.

Comment: @zerkms because there's still a lot of runtime environments that don't?  And anyway, if the behavior never changes then the worst behavior and the best behavior are the same.  The statement is still correct.

Comment: There are even environments without JS support at all. If you want to focus on edge cases - it is a good idea to make it explicitly, otherwise the answer looks misleading and incorrect in terms of the modern standards.

Comment: *"Whether the forEach function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent""* - But strings aren't host objects. This question is about using the function on a string.